# Android: Room Persistence Library: How to cache video/image files?

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, android-room, persistence

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to cache video/image files using Room Persistence Library(aka Repository Pattern).

I am trying to implement a video/image mixed ViewPager with offline caching features.
ex) Instagram feed contains both image and video.

Since Room cannot store media type files, I was planning to store media files in the local storage and store their paths in Room database. So, basically, media files from Network will be stored in the local storage and their path will be store in Room. Then, Repository will retrieve the files from the local path from the Room.

Does this sound efficient for offline caching? If there are other better ways to cache media files, I really appreciate your advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For media related purpose , you should use MediaStore. Post using MediaStore you do not need to implement local database of your own and also it is a much better as well recommended way by Android Team

Comment: Thank you I will look up the documentation for MediaStore.